# Running NFS server as ver 3

Tags: linux, configuration, nfs, version

As NFS docu stands it is possible to run NFS serwer ver 4 as ver 3 from the boot. Just it is necessery to add such entries in /etc/defaults/nfs file:

```
NFS_SERVER_VERSMAX=3
NFS_SERVER_VERSMIN=3
```

I created such file but NFS server sill starts as ver 4. What is wrong in my config?

Comment: Which OS/distribution is this?

Comment: AFAIK the client alone determines/requests which version is used. I guess your setting will only make the nfs-server deny/ignore v4 requests, but not change the behaviour of the system service in any other way.

Comment: I use Mageia ver 4 Linux as server and I set my clients to use ver=3 in call parameters. And I sttill have a problem with mount exported resources. For example I have to use the same UID/GID on clients as on server. In ver 3 it was not necessary. I am not able for me to keep the same GUI/UID on all clients, because most of users are far from me.